# Visual Basic 2012 Array entry into listbox off by 1

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to create an array in which 12 numbers are entered into a text box, read into an array, and shown in the list box.  I need the array to stop at 12 numbers, not 13 and I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim gasArray(11) As Decimal


    Public Sub enterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enterButton.Click
        gasArray(arrayListBox.Items.Count) = Convert.ToDecimal(enterPriceTextBox.Text)
        displayLabel.Text = String.Empty ' clear Label

        For i = 0 To gasArray.GetUpperBound(0) Step 1
            If enterPriceTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
                arrayListBox.Items.Add(enterPriceTextBox.Text)
                enterPriceTextBox.Clear()
            End If
        Next

        enterPriceTextBox.Focus()
        highButton.Enabled = True
        lowButton.Enabled = True
        avgButton.Enabled = True

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close.  Just change this piece:

```
For i = 0 To (gasArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1) Step 1
    If enterPriceTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
        arrayListBox.Items.Add(enterPriceTextBox.Text)
        enterPriceTextBox.Clear()
    End If
Next
```

It's a Base 0, so you need to subtract 1 from the upper bound.